# Is it possible to use f-strings with Concat(), Value() and F()

Tags: django

I have a varchar column whose values I would like to update by concatenating a prefix to a padded integer. Here is what I have tried so far:

```
Item.objects.update(
    field=Concat(
        Value('prefix'), Value(f"{F('id'):>011d}")
        )
    )
```

Which gives me `TypeError: unsupported format string passed to F.__format__`

I need help on how I can achieve this if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that my use case of the f-string was padding, the [LPAD](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#lpad) and [CAST](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/database-functions/#cast) database functions came in handy (I definitely need to study SQL). Here is the update query:

```
Item.objects.update(
    field=Concat(
        Value('prefix'), LPad(Cast('id', output_field=CharField()), 11, Value('0'))
        )
    )
```